# what would cause onResume in Android slow?

Tags: android

what might cause onResume slow? I have set debugging statement for calling onResume and found that calling `super.onResume()` takes 10 seconds to execute. It doesn't happen all the time. It happens to me maybe 1 out of 1000 times when launching the app.

for your references, I didn't have this issue before the implmentation of fb Analytics, fb Ads and Appsflyer. It doesn't seem to be the cause tho, but I just don't understand why this is happening. the slowness might already there but I didn't catch it until now. Any idea why takes super long to execute `super.onResume()` ?

just the general guess on what might cause the issue. the project is kinda big thus posting the code here may not help

Comment: Is this only when the debugger is attached?

Comment: no, it happens very random. hard to reproduce too

Comment: What's the superclass of your activity? Is this happening on devices, emulators, or both?

Comment: superclass is `AppCompatActivity`. i didn't test on emulator, only on devices